# Мутация таблицы во время выполнения триггера SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, plsql, триггер

Здравствуйте, я новичек в PL/SQL и столкнулась с такой проблемой, как мутация таблицы во время выплнения тригерра

Мне надо при при вводе нового поставщика в базу автоматически вводилась запись нового продукта. 
мой код на данный момент

```
create or replace trigger newSuplier
after insert on Suplier
for each row
declare 
s number;
f number;
begin 
select max(id_suplier) into s from suplier;
select max(id_flower) into f from flower;
insert into flower values (f+1, '', 0, s, sysdate);
--где f+1 - новый айди цветка, '' - пустое название, s - айди нового поставщика
END;
/
```

Ошибка в том, что триггер пытался изменить таблицу, которая уже модифицировалась выражением, которое вызвало этот триггер.

Как можно это исправить, если вообще возможно?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала общая рекомендация: Никогда не назначайте ID каких либо объектов получая max(id), это небезопасно, одновременно с вашей транзакцией может работать другая, которая получит и использует тот же самый id. Для назначения ID в Oracle существуют "последовательности" (sequence). Вам надо создать последовательности для всех объектов БД. при желании можно использовать одну для разных объектов, тогда их id никогда не пересекутся. Примерно так `create sequence flower_seq`. Для получения следующего уникального ID следует использовать `select flower_seq.NextVal`.

Я не вижу что бы ваш триггер менял таблицу которая меняется в данном запросе. Вы пытаетесь выполнить select из таблицы `suplier` в построчном триггере на эту же таблицу, это само по себе уже может вызывать ошибку мутации. В построчных (*for each row*) триггерах доступны переменные `:new` и `:old` представляющие обрабатываемые в данный момент записи, все значения для работы надо брать из них.

И еще рекомендую во всех запросах insert явно указывать названия колонок в которые идет вставка, это обезопасит вас от неприятностей в будущем, когда в какой нибудь таблице добавится необязательное поле, а все поголовно insert перестанут работать и их надо будет пересматривать.

С учетом вышесказанного ваш триггер может выглядеть примерно так:

```
create or replace trigger newSuplier
after insert on Suplier
for each row
begin 
  insert into flower(id_flower,name,num,id_suplier,create_date)
  select flower_seq.NextVal, '', 0, :new.id_suplier, sysdate
    from DUAL;
end;
/
```

НО он все таки может вызывать мутацию таблицы в том случае, если у вас существует foreign key ссылающийся с таблицы `flower` на `suplier`, думаю он у вас существует. Этот эффект проявляется не во всех ситуациях. Рекомендую для начала проверить вышеприведенный код, если он вызовет ошибку мутации, то придется прибегнуть к более сложным мерам. Например создать дополнительную таблицу в которую наш триггер будет вставлять в единственное поле значения `:new.id_suplier`. После чего создать второй триггер, уровня запроса (без фразы *for each row*) который из этой таблицы перенесет записи во вторую таблицу:

```
create table new_suppliers(id_suplier number not null);

create or replace trigger newSuplier_row
  after insert on Suplier
    for each row
begin 
   insert into new_suppliers(id_suplier) values(:new.id_suplier);
end;
/
create or replace trigger newSuplier_sta
  after insert on Suplier
begin
  insert into flower(id_flower,name,num,id_suplier,create_date)
  select flower_seq.NextVal, '', 0, id_suplier, sysdate
    from new_suppliers;
  delete from new_suppliers;
end;
/
```